# Hiding Polygons Drawn Using Google Maps Drawing Library

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I can't seem to hide the polygons drawn using the Google Maps Drawing Library. The following is what I am using as my hide function:

```
function hideRectangles() {
  if (rectangles.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
      rectangles[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
}
```

See full example here: http://jsbin.com/wobapopu/2/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never update the `rectangles` array (that is, add rectangles to it), so the `hideRectangles()` does nothing. Add these lines outside your functions `draw/hideRectangles()`

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'rectanglecomplete', function(rectangle) {
  rectangles.push(rectangle);
});
```

[**Click here for Updated example**](http://jsbin.com/wobapopu/4/edit)

Answer (score 1):

You're not pushing actual overlay objects to `rectangles` array, so it can't remove them from the map.

Instead you should do:

```
rectangles.push(e.overlay);
```

Then it will work. Working example [here](http://jsbin.com/widenizi/1/edit)

Comment: Silly mistake. Thank you to both of you for your help.